# Is there a function to parse a ThreadId into an i32 or other primitive?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm looking for a solution to test which threadid my program is in:

```
let t1 = thread::spawn(move|| {
    if thread::current().id() == 2 {
        println!("yes");
    }
});
```

The above fails since it is looking for a `ThreadId`

I have also tried using

```
if thread::current().id() == ThreadId(NonZeroU64::new(2).unwrap()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

But since ThreadId is private this does not work
Also there is an issue currently with `thread::current().id().as_u64()` being unstable.

So I was wondering if there is an easy way to get the number from `thread::current().id()`?

Its possible to print the `thread::current().id()` to the console as `ThreadId(2)` but I'm having trouble trying to compare this to another variable before I join the thread..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by comparing the thread ID to a specific number?

Comment: Agree with @Herohtar.  As documented: "*A `ThreadId` is an **opaque object** that has a unique value for each thread that creates one. `ThreadId`s are **not** guaranteed to correspond to a thread’s system-designated identifier.*"  Comparing with a number serves no purpose.  The only useful thing you can do is compare against another `ThreadId`.

Comment: Well I want a specific thread to do a specific job if I do a batch creation of threads for example doing: 
let threads: Vec<_> = std::iter::repeat(var)
        .take(5)
        .map(|var| thread::spawn(move||{ 
//do work

})).collect();

Comment: Yes I would like to compare against another threadid without joining the thread if thats possible?

Comment: In that case you can just move an index into each thread closure: `(0..5).map(|i| thread::spawn(move || { /* use i */ }).collect()`

Comment: If you have the `JoinHandle` of a thread, you can use the [`thread()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.thread) method to get the thread, and from there its `ThreadId`. No need to join.

Comment: @E_net4theflagger Yes that works :) if you want to make it an answer with example I can mark it correct :)

Comment: @Herohtar ok I will look into that as well! thank you